# what is the correct HTL syntax for get the custom attribute in AEM global request object?

Tags: javascript, html, aem, sightly

I want get the custom attribute in AEM HTL use the request object. this attribute already set to request through javascript use API. like this:

`test.js`

```js
use(function () {
  request.setAttribute('someKey', 'someValue');
});
```

`test.html`

```html
<html data-sly-use.logic="test.js">
<!-- some code ... -->
<body>
  <div>${request.attribute['someKey']}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

result:

```html
<html data-sly-use.logic="test.js">
<!-- some code ... -->
<body>
  <div></div> <!-- empty -->
</body>
</html>
```

We can get request attribute without Java? Many thanks.

Comment: FYI: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Answer (score 1):

Since HTL syntax is rather declarative than imperative, calling methods/functions with parameters is not supported. That means you cannot do something like `${request.getAttribute('someKey')}`. Unfortunately, the Java [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) API does not expose the attributes as a map (it does that for [parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap())) so you cannot do `${request.attributeMap['someKey']}` either, you'll need to fetch the attribute and expose it from your use-object/model.

Comment: Although this answer is right and you should use the use-object for your purpose, the Servlet request doesn't need to expose the attribute as map. You can access the response  object from servlet .

Comment: @Vishal--JAVA--CQ, I think the `test.js` code was used just as a reproduction example (to set a known attribute).

Answer (score 1):

Though you cannot send request attribute the way you are trying to do right now , you can set that as a variable from your server side JS and access it in your code.

In your test.js

```
use(function () {
   return {
    someKey: someValue
   };
});
```

In your test.html

```
<html data-sly-use.logic="test.js">
<!-- some code ... -->
<body>
  <div>${logic.someKey}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This should print the ***someValue*** as output for you.